# Question about transactions added to mempool

Tags: unconfirmed-transactions, mempool

When bitcoin transactions are made, I know that they are put into the mempool. After certain transactions are added to a block and that block gets verified, what happens to all the other transactions that did not meet that threshold? Do they just get rejected?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Do they just get rejected?

No, they will just wait for another block to be included in.

Note that transactions have a time to live in the mempool of 336 hours (configurable using the `maxmempoolexpiry` startup option).

Answer (score 1):

Addition to darosior's answer:

Remember that there's no single mempool - every node maintains its own. Thus a miner can mine a transaction after a long time if it's still valid (its input not spent by another transaction.)